# jQuery plugin uiTableFilter modification

Tags: jquery, filter

How can I modify this plugin to hide the entire table (i.e., the header) if all its rows (tbody) get filtered out? Conversely, when one or more rows re-appear, I want to show the header, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Jay

Comment: can you give the link for the plugin  you are using?

Comment: @gov I think is this one:  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/uiTableFilter

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/uiTableFilter) is says:

> - ifHidden - callback to execute if one or more elements was hidden

So if hou use this callback with [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) you might get what you want.

I you try to do it yourself maybe we can help you with the specifics, but I can't do if for you :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet (from uiTableFilter) looks in each table row to see if it can find the text being searched for (I renamed his method with a nicer name). If it does, it calls one of two methods, either to hide or show that row (matches() or noMatch()).

```
elems.each(function ()
{
    var elem = $(this);
    $.uiTableFilter.FoundSearchString(getText(elem), words, false) ? matches(elem) : noMatch(elem);
}
```

I added the following code after this code. This code is slightly more complex than it might have been simply because I have multiple tables on my screen and I am filtering them all simultaneously. My tables have the class "SearchResultsTable." I simply grab all my tables, iterate over them, getting a count of visible rows in each one. If there are no visible rows, I hide the header, otherwise, I show it.

```
var grids = $(".SearchResultsTable");
grids.each(function()
{
    var grid = $(this);
    var rowCount = grid.find("tbody:first > tr:visible").length;
    if (rowCount > 0)
    {
        grid.find("thead").show();
    }
    else
    {
        grid.find("thead").hide();
    }
});
```